# Опции PHP ./configure

Tags: php, debian

Какие опции ставить в `./configure` при компиляции PHP 5.4 на Debian 7 x64?

У меня стоит PHP, которую поставила *ISPManager*, но не удалось нагуглить, какие опции при сборке были использованы. хотелось бы скомпилировать новую версию, и что бы ничего не слетело.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, опции при сборке можно вывести через `phpinfo(INFO_CONFIGURATION);`

Comment: @tutankhamun Да, действительно, но знать бы еще как все то, что вывелось, привести к виду для ./configure, да и явно что не все там надо трогать, иначе будут десятки опций)

Comment: Только я ошибся. Надо `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);`

Comment: Еще если собрано с поддержкой cli можно вот так `php -i | grep 'Configure Command'`

Comment: вас чем-то не устраивает [дистрибутивный пакет](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php5)?

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

Опции, использованные при сборке, можно вывести с помощью вызова функции `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)`.

А если собрано с поддержкой *cli*, то можно вот так:

```
$ php -i | grep 'Configure Command'
```